# How to remove first character from textfield value?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield

If my textfield takes 11 characters and I need to remove first character and then pass it as a parameter. I tried this code:

```
var dropFirst: String?
if emailPhoneTextField.text?.count == 11 {
    dropFirst = emailPhoneTextField.text?.dropFirst()
    emailPhoneTextField.text = dropFirst 
}
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String.SubSequence?' (aka 'Optional') to type 'String?'

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes its validation is there.. min is 10 0r 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dropFirst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/dropfirst(_:)) returns `SubSequence` so you can't assign it directly to textfield's `text` property that accepts an optional string (`String?`) , So replace

```
dropFirst = emailPhoneTextField.text?.dropFirst()
```

With

```
dropFirst = String(emailPhoneTextField.text!.dropFirst())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create String extension to assign `SubSequence` to `String` property.

```
extension String {
    mutating func removeFirstChar() {
      self = String(self.dropFirst())
    } 
}
```